# SeekBar setProgress trashes secondary progress

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, seekbar

I have primary and secondary progress growing in the same time, secondary progress grows faster than primary.
Everytime I update the primary progress, the secondary one is lost (like it would be zero or less than primary). This produces a nasty flickering.

The only workaround I found is set the secondary to itself after setting the primary. I added "+1" as SeekBar has a check and doesn't redraw if I set the same value.

```
        mSeekBar.setProgress(newPosition);
        mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(mSeekBar.getSecondaryProgress()+1); // WTF?
```

The second line may fix it, but it looks ridiculous and I guess inefficient too.

This happens on Lollipop (5.0.1) - API 21.
It used to work fine before - can't figure out why.

If I build for API level 19 it works fine. (video: [API19Seekbar](http://youtu.be/7Xo1v9GHtJ4))

```
targetSdkVersion 19
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

If I build for API level 21 it flickers. (video: [API21SeekBar](http://youtu.be/_tbGEgp6uJs))

```
targetSdkVersion 21
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
```

Full example Activity code follows:

```
int delay1 = 1000;
int delay2 = 200;
int primaryProgress;
int secondaryProgress;

boolean mStarted;
Button mButton;
SeekBar mSeekBar;
Handler h1 = new Handler();
Handler h2 = new Handler();

Runnable primary = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        primaryProgress = (primaryProgress + 1) % 100;
        mSeekBar.setProgress(primaryProgress);
        h1.postDelayed(primary, delay1);
    }
};

Runnable secondary = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        secondaryProgress = (secondaryProgress + 1) % 100;
        mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(secondaryProgress);
        h2.postDelayed(secondary, delay2);
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonClick();
        }
    });
    mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
}

private void buttonClick() {
    mStarted = !mStarted;
    if (mStarted) {
        mButton.setText("Started");
        h1.postDelayed(primary, delay1);
        h2.postDelayed(secondary, delay2);
    } else {
        mButton.setText("Stopped");
        h1.removeCallbacks(primary);
        h2.removeCallbacks(secondary);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please file a bug on the [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). This is probably either a framework or appcompat issue.

Comment: Thanks Alan! I will. Do you think I can mask this somehow by using a different theme or something?

Comment: So the issue is that `SeekBar`'s default `progressDrawable` has a `<selector>` as it's root, but the root needs to be `<layer-list>`. The best route would probably be to copy `scrubber_progress_horizontal_material.xml` and its 9-patch PNGs from the SDK resources, then to rearrange the tags so that `<layer-list>` is at the root. If you don't need a disabled state, that's as simple as dropping the outer element and extra disabled state item.

Comment: Did you find a way to permanent way to fix it?

Comment: check out the answer to your other comment (in the solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed for the next Android release, but the best workaround for now would probably be to copy `scrubber_progress_horizontal_material.xml` and its 9-patch PNGs from the SDK resources (`<sdk-root>/platforms/android-21/data/res/...`), then to rearrange the tags so that `<layer-list>` is at the root.

Here is what the revised XML should look like:

drawable-v21/scrubber_progress_horizontal_material_fixed.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            android:src="@drawable/scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha"
            android:tint="?android:attr/colorControlNormal" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <selector>
                <item android:state_enabled="false">
                    <color android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                </item>
                <item>
                    <nine-patch
                        android:src="@drawable/scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha"
                        android:tint="?android:attr/colorControlNormal" />
                </item>
            </selector>
        </scale>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <selector>
                <item android:state_enabled="false">
                    <color android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                </item>
                <item>
                    <nine-patch
                        android:src="@drawable/scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha"
                        android:tint="?android:attr/colorControlActivated" />
                </item>
            </selector>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And then the appropriate changes in `values-v21/styles.xml` and/or your layout XML so that you use this background by default on API 21+. I can include examples for those if you need them.

Comment: Thank you Alan I will try this soon. Is a bug still needed in this case?

Comment: I'm still having the same problem with API21+, build tools version 23.0.2

Comment: Yes it is fixed. Stop looking for workarounds and use the latest SDK and Support libs:`compileSdkVersion 23 /
 targetSdkVersion - doesn't matter (19, 21, 23 etc) /
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'` I have shared a mini-project you can use to test: https://github.com/rumburake/TestSeekBar