# SeekBar secondaryProgress not showing

Tags: android, progress, seekbar

I have a question, I have a seek bar and I want to show the buffer progress of an ExoPlayer media file using the secondary progress bar of the seekBar, the problem is that it´s not showing. Im running on API 21
Here´s the xml code:

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarAudioA"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:maxHeight="3dip"
                android:minHeight="3dip"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress"
                android:secondaryProgressTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:thumbTint="@color/amber"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_pause"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/play_pause"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_pause" />
```

and here´s the java code:

```
 SeekBar = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (currentlyPlaying && currentAudioHolder.getAdapterPosition() == audioPosition) {
                    int duration = (int) exoPlayer.getDuration();
                    currentAudioHolder.seekBarAudio.setMax(duration);
                    currentAudioHolder.seekBarAudio.setSecondaryProgress((int) exoPlayer.getBufferedPosition());
                    final int currPosition = (int) exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    Log.d("Buffer", "secondary progress bar position is: " + (int) exoPlayer.getBufferedPosition() + ", and the current position is: " + currPosition);
                    currentAudioHolder.seekBarAudio.setProgress(currPosition);
                    ((ChatActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            currentAudioHolder.audioLength.setText(convertTime(currPosition));
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException i) {
                currentlyPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    });
    SeekBar.start();
```

Please help :(

Comment: 'it´s not showing ' means seek bar not showing or seek bar not showing progress? if it is not displaying plz check your layout once again,maybe you have placed it wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290950/seekbar-setprogress-trashes-secondary-progress

Comment: can you post your @drawable/seek_bar_progress file , did you try  adding  a color for secondary progress in this file?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but here is my answer: you should check your `seek_bar_progress` file, that you use for `android:progressDrawable`, and see if it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/myBgColor"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/myColor"/>
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item> <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/myColor"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I found out that the part with the `@android:id/secondaryProgress` id was missing in my drawable, and that was the reason why it was not working for me.

Hope it helps.